# PHP: foreach inside while loop returning only one result

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Having issues trying to perform a foreach within a while loop in PHP.  I'm extracting build names from a database table.  Those build names happen to be folder names.  Within those folders is a folder (either Client or Clients) and within those are folders named after the clients business name.  I want the script to show me the build name (accomplished already with an echo) and then list each folder below the build name.

```
$build_grab = mysql_query("SELECT b_id,b_name FROM builds", $link);
while($build_row = mysql_fetch_array($build_grab))
{
  $b_id = $build_row['b_id'];
  $b_name = $build_row['b_name'];

  $client_dir = is_dir("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Client/");
  $clients_dir = is_dir("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Clients/");

  if ($client_dir == '1') {
    $client_folders = explode(",", exec("ls -1 /somepath/builds/$b_name/Client/"));
  } elseif ($clients_dir == '1') {
    $client_folders = str_replace("\n","", explode(",", exec("ls -1 /somepath/builds/$b_name/Clients/")));
  };

  echo $b_name;
  echo "\r\n";

  foreach($client_folders as $folder)
  {
    echo $folder;
    echo "\r\n";
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this seems to only give me one (1) client folder name per build and it's always the last client (a-z) in the folder.

Example Output:

> build-4.0.0.0
> Client-f
> build-4.0.0.1
> Client-d
> build-4.0.0.2
> Client-j

What am I missing here or better yet, is there a more efficient way of doing this?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` library. Use either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: I did not check your code but you probably initialize the variable in the for loop ( or the while loop ) so all the other is overriden every time you enter the for or the while loop.

Comment: `foreach($folder as $subfolder) { // ... stuff ... }`

Comment: Please, if you decide to ask your question on StackOverflow, take a few minutes to format your code properly. It is soo much easier to read code if it has proper indentation.

Comment: Chris - Thanks for your msyqli suggestion, I'll take that into consideration however at this time extracting data from the DB isn't an issue.
Koray - If you would please elaborate and point out any errors I would really appreciate the help.
Amal - I'm already using that syntax, thanks.
Sumurai8 - Sorry for the format issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks much to mcrumley, your suggestion of using 'glob' fixed it!  Sorry crumley, I am apparently to newb to vote up your response.  Perhaps other users can help with that.
Thanks also Chris for suggesting mysqli, I will code with it from here out, late adopter here.

Below the new code that resolved the issue.

```
$build_grab = $mysqli->query("SELECT b_id,b_name FROM builds");
  while($build_row = $build_grab->fetch_array())
{
  $b_id = $build_row['b_id'];
  $b_name = $build_row['b_name'];

  $client_dir = is_dir("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Client/");
  $clients_dir = is_dir("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Clients/");

  if ($client_dir == '1') {
    $client_folders = glob("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Client/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
  } elseif ($clients_dir == '1') {
    $client_folders = glob("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Clients/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
  };

  echo $b_name;
  echo "\r\n";

  foreach($client_folders as $folder)
  {
    echo $folder;
    echo "\r\n";
  }
}
```

Thanks again for everyones help!

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the $client_folders variable each time. You want to create it as an array before you enter the while loop, then do this

```
if ($client_dir == '1') {
  $client_folders[] = explode(",", exec("ls -1 /somepath/builds/$b_name/Client/"));
} elseif ($clients_dir == '1') {
  $client_folders[] = str_replace("\n","", explode(",", exec("ls -1 /somepath/builds/$b_name/Clients/")));
};
```

By the way, this will only enter the first IF, since the second is exactly the same

Comment: It is intended to be repeated in the while loop because there is a possibility of either a Client or Clients (with s) within each build folder.  Apparently standardization of folder structures wasn't strong in this environment.  The purpose of the if is to muddle through that.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `s` on the if. Gotcha

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
$client_folders = str_replace("\n","", explode(",", exec("ls -1 /somepath/builds/$b_name/Clients/")));
```

I would recommend using the following code to list the folders.

```
if ($folderHandle = opendir(clients_dir)) {
    while ($file = readdir($folderHandle) {
        echo "$file\n";
    }
    closedir($folderHandle);
}
```

You can change that code to be conditional, but it should give you a good list.

Comment: Or `$client_folders = glob("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Client/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR)`

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` only returns the last line of output from the command. You should use the native PHP functions to read the directory list - either `opendir`/`readdir` or `glob` will work.

```
if ($client_dir == '1') {
  $client_folders = glob("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Client/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
} elseif ($clients_dir == '1') {
  $client_folders = glob("/somepath/builds/$b_name/Clients/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
};
```

Comment: If you **must** use `exec()` You could do this: `unset $client_folders; exec("ls -1 ...", $client_folders);` to capture each line of output in an array.